# PHP Image upload - spot the error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small problem with my PHP image upload code, I`m not getting the correct file name to be saved to my MySQL database.

Please tell me what im doing wrong.

**PHP**:

```
// Upload File to Directory
$code = md5(time());
$image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$imagename = $code.$image;
$uploaddir = '../_gallery/' . $imagename;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

**MySQL query**:

```
$sql="UPDATE b_events 
      SET ename = '$event_name', 
          edescription = '$event_description', 
          edate = '$event_date', 
          etime = '$event_time', 
          ecost = '$event_cost', 
          eimage = '$imagename' 
      WHERE id = '$update'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: what result do you expect to get and what result are you getting ?

Comment: Im getting the file name, trying to rename it with md5, file is uploaded correctly with new name, but not to the database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to insert this name to your database becuase you upload file into directory by this name

or by assigning values to new variable

```
$sql="UPDATE b_events 
          SET ename = '$event_name', 
              edescription = '$event_description', 
              edate = '$event_date', 
              etime = '$event_time', 
              ecost = '$event_cost', 
              eimage = '$uploadfile' 
        WHERE id = '$update'";
```

OR

```
  $file_name =basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$sql="UPDATE b_events 
          SET ename = '$event_name', 
              edescription = '$event_description', 
              edate = '$event_date', 
              etime = '$event_time', 
              ecost = '$event_cost', 
              eimage = '$file_name' 
        WHERE id = '$update'";
```

Comment: Im still getting only the file name "image.jpg", it hould be something like "0fec90395c188efea02300c1dabf7950image.jpg".

Comment: ok u need to use this variable for insertion $imagename which you make by concatenation of md5 and file

Comment: tried that on my post, not working, not getting the full name to be inserted to the database, just that the file uploads 100% correctly with the name change and not the the database itself.

Comment: Used variable $uploadfile and now working correctly by uploading the renamed file to the directory and saving the file name to the database.

Comment: I have it solved, is there a way to resize the image though the code above? need it resized.